# Button click issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to refer the button to another page using :to. It doesn't do anything at the moment. For testing purposes I'm now trying to refer to the existing /learn page.

My code:

```
  <b-navbar-item tag="div">
                <div class="buttons">
                    <a class="button is-primary"
                v-for="item in menuItems" 
                :key="item.title"
                :to="item.link">
                        {{item.title}}
                        </a>    
                </div>
            </b-navbar-item>
```

```
export default {
    data() {
      return {
           menuItems: [
       { title: 'Login', link: '/learn'},
       { title: 'Sign up', link: '/learn'},
       { title: 'Logout', link: '/learn'},

      ]
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Vue Router? I'm not a Vue.js expert, but I believe the `v-bind:to` attribute is used on `<router-link>` components. For regular links using the `<a>` tag, you can use `v-bind:href` or `:href` to assign the link:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    menuItems: [{
        title: 'Login',
        link: '/link1'
      },
      {
        title: 'Sign up',
        link: '/link2'
      },
      {
        title: 'Logout',
        link: '/link3'
      },
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="buttons">
    <a class="button is-primary" v-for="item in menuItems" :key="item.title" :href="item.link">
      {{item.title}}
    </a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For this to work you need to use `VueRouter` and instead of the `<a>` tag you need to use the `<router-link>` component. 
If you really need to use a `<a>` tag you can also use the [scoped-slot](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#v-slot-api-3-1-0)  of `<router-link>`

```
<router-link
  to="/foo"
  v-slot="{ href, route, navigate, isActive, isExactActive }"
>
  <li
    :class="[isActive && 'router-link-active', isExactActive && 'router-link-exact-active']"
  >
    <a :href="href" @click="navigate">{{ route.fullPath }}</a>
  </li>
</router-link>
```